# Chrome Login Data returns None sqlite3

Tags: python, google-chrome, sqlite

I am writing a script in Python to dump my Google Chrome passwords (in Linux) in a file but when I connect to the database it returns None, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
path = os.getenv('HOME') + '/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login Data'
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')
for result in ex.fetchall():
```

Comment: Are you sure that the db isn't locked?  When I do this within python I don't get an error but from the command line I get this: `sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Login\ Data '.tables'`
`Error: database is locked`

Comment: Yes, the db is locked when chrome is opened, basically my db is like empty